# Blocking call to X509ExtendedKeyManager#chooseClientAlias

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate

I want to implement a custom X509KeyManager which has the logic to return a specific client identity.
The client identity can be selected by showing a UI to the user and based on the selection same should be returned by
`chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket)`..

One solution is to block the caller of this callback till the selection is made.But i am not sure how safe this will be.

Please let me know if there is proper way to achieve this. Other wise i would have make the selection prior of any SSL handshake event.

Also i want to know if there is any caching done by the lower layers in java/Android for SSL handshake. 
Is there any kind of time out for same host port combination i.e for the same host port, SSL handshake will not happen till the time out occurs?
Like for example iOS NSURLConnection maintains a timeout of 10 minutes(no SSL handshake) for the same host port combination.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to have X509ExtendedKeyManager wrapper class ? In my case overriding methods chooseClientAlias or chooseEngineClientAlias never getting called !

Answer (score 1):

> One solution is to block the caller of this callback till the selection is made.But I am not sure how safe this will be.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'safe' so I can't address this item. The SSL handshake can't proceed until this method returns so certainly it can't compromise SSL. It might cause the peer to timeout however. I don't consider that a 'safety' risk, but you might,

> Please let me know if there is proper way to achieve this. Other wise i would have make the selection prior of any SSL handshake event.

Again I don't know what you mean by 'proper'. Browsers do exactly what you're proposing, if that's any help.

> Also i want to know if there is any caching done by the lower layers in java/Android for SSL handshake.

SSL sessions are cached, and their trust material (shared secrets, session key, certificates).

> Is there any kind of time out for same host port combination i.e for the same host port, SSL handshake will not happen till the time out occurs? Like for example iOS NSURLConnection maintains a timeout of 10 minutes(no SSL handshake) for the same host port combination.

I don't know what this means. The NSURLConnection timeout appears to be like all other timeouts: it sets a maximum time for the response to appear, which if exceeded causes an error condition. It doesn't have the effect you claim. The default value appears to be 4 minutes, not ten. If you're asking about how to set a read timeout, the answer is in the documentation. If you're asking whether there is a read timeout by default, the answer is no.

Comment: Hi @EJP thanks for your answer, just to add to my question:
With safe i mean that lower layers may have some time out / peer time out for the SSL handshake and we can expect some delay from the end user for the selection to complete. Hence, chances of getting peer timeout are very high.

For your comment Session timeout are cached (secrets , session keys , certificates) I did not see such behavior as i always get the chooseClientAlias callback when i execute the same request. The request endpoint is protected using 2-way SSL scheme. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne, do you have a good example of X509ExtendedKeyManager wrapper class ? In my case overriding methods chooseClientAlias or chooseEngineClientAlias never getting called !